# ext-6 gpl hello world

Tags: javascript, css, extjs6

i want to build applications with extjs, i downloaded the GPL version from sencha.com, in me html file i have the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../lib/extjs/build/resources/ext-watermark/style.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <title>Test ExtJs version 6</title>     
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../lib/extjs/build/ext-all-debug.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../lib/extjs/build/ext-all.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="testExtJsscript.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Test ExtJs</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

and in me testExtJsscript.js  i have the code:

```
function mess(){
 Ext.MessageBox.alert('info','Extjs4 est pret');
 }

 Ext.onReady(mess);
```

but the result is just like in the photo
[image]

i think that the problem is i haven't the right css file, in all documents there is a ext-all.css file and i can not find it?

I tried to install the trial version of sencha extjs, but the extraction is not working, i reach 42 % and i have problems (CRS faild) with *.png files

thanks for your help

Comment: Follow the getting started guide: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/getting_started/getting_started.html

Comment: thanks for your answer, my goal is to use the library ExtJs with installing anything, just importing the ext-all.js and ext-all-debug.js and ext-all.css

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are missing the css file. But anyway, you should not write the html file with the inclusion of the css and js files yourself. You should use Sencha Cmd right from the start, as @Evan suggests. http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/guides/getting_started/getting_started.html

Answer (score 0):

The minimal html should be like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link  href="/ext/6.0.0/build/classic/theme-triton/resources/theme-triton-all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script src="/ext/6.0.0/build/ext-all.js"></script>
        <script src="/ext/6.0.0/build/classic/theme-triton/theme-triton.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            Ext.onReady(function() {
                Ext.Msg.alert('Welcome', 'Hello, World!');
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

See my online demos here:

[ExtJS 6 Hello World Application](https://ext4all.com/post/extjs-6-hello-world-application.html)

[ExtJS 6 Hello World Application Using Ext Loader](https://ext4all.com/post/extjs-6-hello-world-application-using-ext-loader.html)

[ExtJS 6 "Hello World" Application - Modern Toolkit](https://ext4all.com/post/extjs-6-hello-world-application-modern-toolkit.html)